# Reset a cumulative total when 0 is entered

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column that numbers are entered and the column next to it calculates the cumulative total.

```
   |...|   H   |   I   |
 1 |...|       |       |
...|...|       |       |
16 |...|  100  |  100  |
17 |...|       |       |
18 |...|       |       |
19 |...|  100  |  200  |
20 |...|  100  |  300  |
21 |...|       |       |
22 |...|  100  |  400  |
...|...|       |       |
```

I am using this in the first cell 
`I16` = `=IF(H16="","",H16)`.
The following cells in the column are, 
`I17` = `=IF(H17="","",SUM($H$16:H17))`, 
`I18` = `=IF(H18="","",SUM($H$16:H18))` 
`I19` = `=IF(H19="","",SUM($H$16:H19))` 
and so on.

I would like the reset the cumulative total in column `I` to `0`, if there's a `0` entered column `H`.

The simple solution is taking the value in `H` and add it to `I` but that doesn't work if there's no values entered, which is common, like in the example.  So, something like `=IF(H17=0,0,I16+H17)` and so on will not work as a `null` would miscalculate the cumulative total.

I would like the end result to look like this;

```
   |...|   H   |   I   |
 1 |...|       |       |
...|...|       |       |
16 |...|  100  |  100  |
17 |...|       |       |
18 |...|       |       |
19 |...|  100  |  200  |
20 |...|   0   |   0   |
21 |...|       |       |
22 |...|  100  |  100  |
...|...|       |       |
```

I'm open to any ideas to accomplish my task.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An INDIRECT ADDRESS Helper Column Solution

The second formula is (sadly) just for cell `J16`, the others are to be copied down. The formulas in column `J` can be `Cut/Paste`d to another column.

```
[I16] =IF(H16="","",SUM(INDIRECT(J16&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(H16),COLUMN(H16)))))
[J16] =ADDRESS(ROW(H16),COLUMN(H16))
[J17] =IF(H17="",J16,IF(H17=0,ADDRESS(ROW(H17),COLUMN(H17)),J16))
```

[image]

BTW, in your current setup you can safely copy the formula from `I17` to `I16`. There is no need for different formulas.

Comment: I have an additional question regarding this style of edit.  

I have another set of cells that will be cumulative so, as above 'H16 = 100' then 'I16 = 100', 'H17 = 300' then 'I17 = 200', 'H18' is 'null', 'H19 = 500' then 'I19 = 200' and so on, much like above only reversed.  

I am using '=IF(H16="","", H16)' in 'I16' and '=IF(H17<>"",IF(COUNT(H$16:H16),H17-LOOKUP(2,1/(H$16:H16<>""),H$16:H16),""),"")' in 'I17' copied down.

Is there a way to use your example to restart the cumulative total in H when a 0 is added?  So if H20 = 0 then H21 can be 100 again.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I believe I have the solution after playing around with the above formula.  =IF(H17="","",IF(H17<>0,IF(COUNT(H$16:H16),H17-LOOKUP(2,1/(H$16:H16<>""),H$16:H16),""),0))

Comment: Using `my values` in `H17:H29` and by using `your first formula` I get the following results in `I17:I29`: `0,0,-100,200,-70,,125,,-95,-160,35,-35,225`. By using `your second formula` I get the following results  in `I17:I29`: `0,0,0,200,-70,,125,,-95,0,35,0,225`. Can you tell me what are `your desired results` in `I17:I29` (comma-separated) using `my values` in `H17:H29`?

Comment: In cell H16 and I16 I have a protected cell with 0 the same color as the worksheet vbWhite.  In my sheet this line is never used for any totals so I can get away with this.  In cell I17, I have the above code.  This is a running cumulative total until a 0 is entered. So, H17 = 100, H18 = 200, H19 = 300 making I17 = 100, I18 = 100 and I19 = 100 for each "stage".  If I enter 0 in H20, I20 = 0 and a new value range can be started. H21 = 100, H22 = 300 and H23 = 500 making I21 = 100, I22 = 200 and I23 = 200.  I'm sorry I don't know how to format my questions yet.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize that you presented the solution in your second comment. And without the helper column. Brilliant! Then I guess similarly you can do it for the first case, too. How does this `Lookup` work. I mean what does `1/(H$16:H16<>"")` mean? Does it mean 'search from the bottom to the top'?

Comment: It's the copied down value.  In cell `I30` the formula is `=IF(H30="","",IF(H30<>0,IF(COUNT(H$16:H29),H30-LOOKUP(2,1/(H$16:H29<>""),H$16:H29),""),0))` it just looks up the last value over 0.  So, yes, it searches bottom up like you said.  Again I want to thank you for the direction I needed to get this accomplished, I appreciate your time.